# IdentityServer Admin: how to include Admin.EntityFramework?

Tags: entity-framework, identityserver3, identityserver4

I am exploring IdentityServer and noticed 
 https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Admin and https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Admin.EntityFramework repositories.

I understand that Admin is the core UI project, Admin EF is a persisting layer for the core.
Out-of-the box Admin uses in-memory generated data.
But I couldn't find how I should replace In-Memory provider with Admin EF persisting layer.

Can anyone give me any tutorial/documentation/steps to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of using Admin.EntityFramework within that repository. Check here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Admin.EntityFramework/tree/master/source/Host